# ¿Como puedo cargar un fichero excel en python con openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Estoy usando openpyxl para trabajar con hojas de excel en python. No soy capaz de abrir el workbook introduciendo la ruta del fichero o únicamente el nombre introducido mediante una variable. ¿Como lo podría solucionar?

```
nombreFichero = 'hojaexcel.xlsx'
fichero = openpyxl.load_workbook(nombreFichero)
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
fichero = openpyxl.load_workbook(nombreFichero)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__     
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con la librería pandas

Comment: @christian es que si pongo `fichero = openpyxl.load_workbook('hojaexcel.xlsx')` me lo coge bien, para no cambiar todo el código que tengo implementado si uso pandas

Comment: Prueba agregando el atributo ```filename = 'hoja excelente.xls'``` y comprueba si haces esto ```from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')```

Comment: Esta pregunta en ingles da varias posibles soluciones a diferentes causas del error. Desde que el archivo tenga contraseña hasta que no haya sido creado todavía o esté abierto antes de correr el codigo. [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873423/xlsx-and-xlsm-files-return-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file)